# I can't understand why this if statement doesn't work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My app involves two `UILabels` `labelDisplay` and `labelStatus`, one `UIButton`, `buttonAddOne`, and a variable `numbers`. I can't understand why the `labelStatus` isn't being updated when `numbers` reaches 5.

```
import UIKit

var numbers:Int = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Declaration of the two labels
    @IBOutlet weak var labelDisplay: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelStatus: UILabel!

    // Code for the "Add 1" button
    @IBAction func buttonAddOne(sender: AnyObject) {
        numbers = numbers + 1
        labelDisplay.text = "\(numbers)"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if numbers == 5 {
            labelStatus.text = "Numbers variable is equal to 5! Hurray!"
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you put in `viewDidLoad` is executed once, when the view is loaded - it isn't triggered every time `numbers` is updated.

To implement what you need, you should make `number` an instance property, and add a `didSet` observer:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var numbers: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            if numbers == 5 {
                labelStatus.text = "Numbers variable is equal to 5! Hurray!"
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The property observer is automatically executed when the property value is changed.

For more info read [Property Observers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_390)

Answer (score 1):

> I can't understand why the labelStatus isn't being updated when "numbers" reaches 5

What would update it? The code inside `viewDidLoad`? But `viewDidLoad` is called once, early, when the view controller gets its view; it will never be called again, so that code will never run again.

If you want to update `labelStatus`, why don't you do it in the same code that increments `numbers`?

```
@IBAction func buttonAddOne(sender: AnyObject) {
    numbers = numbers + 1
    labelDisplay.text = "\(numbers)"
    if numbers == 5 {
        labelStatus.text = "Numbers variable is equal to 5! Hurray!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. Would you mind suggesting a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. That is a good suggestion. However, I'd like to trigger the labelStatus without the action of the button.

Comment: I thought you might. In that case, Antonio's way is the Swifty way!